# Generating xml with LXML - attribute namespace

Tags: python, lxml

I need to generate xml which looks like this:

```
<definitions xmlns:ex="http://www.example1.org" xmlns="http://www.example2.org">
  <typeRef xmlns:ns2="xyz">text</typeRef>
</definitions>
```

My code looks as follows:

```
class XMLNamespaces:
    ex = 'http://www.example1.org' 
    xmlns = 'http://www.example2.org'

root = Element('definitions', xmlns='http://www.example2.org', nsmap = {'ex':XMLNamespaces.ex})
type_ref = SubElement(root, 'typeRef')
type_ref.attrib[QName(XMLNamespaces.xmlns, 'ns2')] = 'xyz'
type_ref.text = 'text'

tree = ElementTree(root)
tree.write('filename.xml', pretty_print=True)
```

The result looks like:

```
<definitions xmlns:ex="http://www.example1.org" xmlns="http://www.example2.org">
  <typeRef xmlns:ns0="http://www.example2.org" ns0:ns2="xyz">text</typeRef>
</definitions>
```

So here is my question:

How to make attribute look like **xmlns:ns2="xyz"** instead of **xmlns:ns0="http://www.example2.org" ns0:ns2="xyz"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run same process as your opening element where you defined the namespace dictionary with *nsmap* argument. Notice the added variable in your class object:

```
from lxml.etree import *

class XMLNamespaces:
    ex = 'http://www.example1.org' 
    xmlns = 'http://www.example2.org'
    xyz = 'xyz'

root = Element('definitions', xmlns='http://www.example2.org', nsmap={'ex':XMLNamespaces.ex})
type_ref = SubElement(root, 'typeRef', nsmap={'ns2':XMLNamespaces.xyz})
type_ref.text = 'text'

tree = ElementTree(root)
tree.write('filename.xml', pretty_print=True)

# <definitions xmlns:ex="http://www.example1.org" xmlns="http://www.example2.org">
#   <typeRef xmlns:ns2="xyz">text</typeRef>
# </definitions>
```